# Making the width of pseudo a::after as the container

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make a transition to some 'a' tags. And which is that when it is mouse hovered, the underline is slowly grow from the left to the right on its text string.

I figured that I should make it with pseudo of the a tag, I succeed to make a similar transition, but it has a problem that make me stuck.

```css
.test a {
  font-size: 5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.test a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0.1em;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 0;
}

.test a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href="#">text for the test</a>
</div>
```

I make the transition to change width of a::after from 0 to 100%
but width 100% is rendered by the size of .test, not to the size of 'a'. So the length of underline doesn't fits to the text. It fits to the screen size.

I cannot understand that why a::after doesn't follow the size of its parent, a. And want to know how can I make a::after to follow the size of 'a'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add:

```
.test {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

or

```
.test a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

So that the size of the box matches the content.

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
}

.test a {
  font-size: 5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.test a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0.1em;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 0;
}

.test a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href="#">text for the test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow Genius :O Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea without the use of pseudo element and without the issue of size:

```css
.test a {
  font-size: 5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  padding-bottom:0.1em;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#000,#000);
  background-size:0% 0.1em;
  background-position:0 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.test a:hover {
  background-size:100% 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <a href="#">text for the test</a>
</div>
```